# calculating p-value from PRE (proportional reduction in error)

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, linear-model

In R, I have created a PRE value to test whether or not modelA is significantly different from modelC. How can I get a significance value for either the PRE distribution or the R^2 distribution (pearson's R)?

```
#modelA<-lm(...)
#modelC<-lm(...)
PRE=(sum(modelC$residuals^2)-sum(modelA$residuals^2))/sum(modelC$residuals^2)
```

Comment: Are they nested models? If so a small rescaling of your formula should yield a standard partial F (discussed in a number of questions here). If they're not nested, most people would use some criterion for comparison rather than a test (such as comparing AIC or BIC, for example), but it's possible to use something like Vuong's test.

Comment: An F test would work, I was hoping someone knew of a way to get the PRE distribution critical values in R though.

Comment: You can back them straight out of the F-test

Answer (score -1):

There is no PRE distribution. You just have to use your judgement if the reduction in error seems large enough to justify adding complexity to the model.